# Why SQLAlchemy bulk update mappings operation can be slow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have an ETL job where I mass update around 150k rows. The [`bulk_update_mappings`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.bulk_update_mappings) runs for around 90 mins:

```
session.bulk_update_mappings(cls, object_list)
```

Here `session` has `autocommit` set to `False`. I suspect that this has to do with how SQLAlchemy deals with `None`s in the dictionaries, so I would like to understand how `UPDATE`s are prepared.

- How `None` are handled in the mappings?
- Are there multiple `UPDATE` issued based on non-null column combinations?
- Would it help if I preorder the objects based on which columns are null?
- Would updating in chunks help?
- Would it be faster to just update those that really needs to be updated, ie fetch data first, compare and update?

I am using Python 3.6 with SQLAlchemy 1.3.0. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: Which rdbms you use and which driver? Updates can be slower than inserts depends on the use case.

Comment: PostgreSQL with psycopg2 2.7, but I want my implementation to be RDBMS independent.

Comment: You can use the same code, but each driver have own implementations with different kind of performances. Since you doing a ETL job, probably you don't need an update but some kind of insert where you can see the current value easily, but you still have the old values somewhere for historical analysis.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue and what I can see in the db (postgres) on `pg_stat_activity` is that sqlalchemy is sending a single `UPDATE` query per row. And in my case is taking roughly 100ms/row, which can easily be really time consuming.